# Invalid prop type supplied

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a React route defined in my app as:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
```

The component loads the user from the store then depending on the type does a redirect. It is defined as:

```
import React, { useEffect, memo } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useInjectSaga } from '../../utils/injectSaga'
import {
  makeSelectCurrentUser,
  makeSelectLoading,
  makeSelectError
} from '../../containers/App/selectors'
import { loadUser } from '../../containers/App/actions'
import saga from '../../components/Header/saga'

const key = 'home'

function Home({ user, loading, error, loadUser }) {
  useInjectSaga({ key, saga })

  const username = localStorage.getItem('username')
  useEffect(() => {
    loadUser(username)
  }, [])

  return !loading && user && !error ? (
    <Redirect to={user.type === 'admin' ? '/admin' : '/promoter'} />
  ) : (
    <div>Loading...</div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  user: makeSelectCurrentUser(),
  loading: makeSelectLoading(),
  error: makeSelectError()
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loadUser: username => dispatch(loadUser(username))
  }
}

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)

export default compose(withConnect, memo)(Home)
```

When I execute the code, it works. However, I get a warning in the console:

```
index.js:1437 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `PrivateRoute`.
```

It points to the line with my "home" route.

What am I doing wrong? How should this be done?

Comment: What is `PrivateRoute`?

Comment: a standard thing like:
``` ... 
    const render = props =>
    isAuthenticated === true ? <Component {...props} /> : null

    return <Route path={path} render={render} {...rest} />```

Comment: The warning is coming from there. Maybe you should add the component to your question

Comment: it's an Auth0 `PrivateRoute` from https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login

Comment: Ok thanks I found the [source code](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/blob/master/01-Login/src/components/PrivateRoute.js). Can you show more about where its getting used? Like how you import `Home`?

Comment: with an `import`, just like all other components.

Comment: Default or named?

Comment: `import Home from '../Home'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Once I did the below, the problem went away.

`<PrivateRoute path="/home" component={() => <Home/>} />`

Still weird, yet the latter is obviously valid no matter what. Seems like a bug in react-router, maybe.